# How to show data in FlatList in React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am learning react-native and trying to fetch data from API and showing it in the flat list but I am not getting an idea of how can I do that in functional component as I have been through many tutorials on the internet but all of them uses class-based components.

Below is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const List = () => {

const[post,setPost] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    
    const url = 'http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=simpsons+characters&format=json';
    fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
    .then((resp) => console.warn(resp))
    .catch((err) => console.warn(err));
},[]);

    return(
      <View>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hello there</Text>
      </View>
    );

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 testStyle:{
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent:"center",
     alignItems:"center"
   }
});

export default List;
```

Data I have successfully retrieved from the server but How can I show this data in FlatList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to save your response in your state to refer later on. And then use Flatlist component of react-native

```
const List = () => {

const[post,setPost] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    
    const url = 'http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=simpsons+characters&format=json';
    fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
    .then((resp) => setPost(resp.RelatedTopics))
    .catch((err) => console.warn(err));
},[]);

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.Text}</Text>
  );

    return(
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={post}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.FirstURL}
        />
      </View>
    );
};
```

Refer [this official doc with example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

First you'd want to take a look at the docs. I didn't read the docs when I started playing around with FlatList and wrote my own buggy, confusing code to figure out what items were on-screen. While trying to make it less buggy, I found an amazingly simple way of doing that. It will save you time, I promise.

With that said you are going to want a few items

1. Your list (you have).
2. a component that renders a single item of your list. This component will have two relevant props: index and item. Index is as you have probably guessed, and item is data the list item has

   So assuming you have a list like this

   ```js
   const data = [
     {name:"Harry Potter", phone:1234},
     {name:"Ron Weasley", phone:4321}
   ]
   ```

   Your renderItem component may look like:

   ```js
   const renderItem=({index,item})=>{
   let style = [{fontSize:14}]
   // if first item give it spacing at top
   if(index == 0)
     style.push({paddingTop:5})
   return(  
     <View style={style}>
       <Text>Name:{item.name}</Text>
       <Text>Phone:{item.phone}</Text>
     </View>
   )
   })
   ```
3. A keyExtractor function, which should generate a string unique for all components in your app for each item of your list.

Bring this all together and you get:

```js
 <FlatList
     data={data}
     renderItem={renderItem}
     keyExtractor={(item,key) => item.id || 'harry-potter-character'+i}
 />
```